# Probability of $4$ "S" in a row in permutations of Mississippi

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In a random order of the letters *MISSISSIPPI*, what is the probability that all S’s are together?

The books says the answer is $$\frac{\frac{8!}{4!2!}}{\frac{11!}{4!4!2!}}=\frac{840}{34650}\approx 0.024$$

While I agree with the numerator, I disagree with the denominator. I don't see why we are only considering distinguishable permutations of Mississippi when some permutations of Mississippi albeit repeated, occur more often.

So similar to how if parents gave birth to two kids, what is the probability that they have a boy and a girl? Well, the sample space is $\{bb,bg,gb,gg\}$ and NOT $\{bb,gb,gg\}$ so the probability is $0.5$ not $0.\overline{33}$.

If the question had said, of the distinguishable permutations, what is the probability of having $4$ S in a row, then I agree with the book's solution.

Am I correct in thinking so? Or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I realize now that I shouldn't agree with the numerator either for the same reasons I disagree with the denominator.

Comment: All "distinguishable" permutations of the letters M,I,S,S,I,S,S,I,P,P,I are equally probable, because each of them comes out of exactly $4!\cdot 4!\cdot 2!$ "basic"/"non-distinguishable" permutations (i.e. those where you can tell the "same" letters from each other) - basically giving you the same result regardless of whether you can distinguish the "same" letters or not.

Comment: Can you help me reconcile why the boy-girl case is different? @StinkingBishop

Comment: I guess because in that case your events $bb=\{bb\}, gb=\{bg,gb\}, gg=\{gg\}$ are not of the same size, so even if the "elementary" events ($bb,bg,gb,gg$) are equally probable, those three events are not. With Mississippi, though, all $\frac{11!}{4!4!2!}$ events contain $4!4!2!$ elementary events each.

Comment: RIGHT! that makes sense, thank you @StinkingBishop

Comment: You could simplify this even more but only thinking about the positions of the four S's. There are $C(11,4)$ equally likely locations for the (set of four) S's, of which exactly $8$ lie in consectutive spots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a bag containing the $11$ letters of MISSISSIPPI.

Draw the letters one by one and place them in a row.

The probability on a result *starting* with SSSS is:$$\frac4{11}\frac3{10}\frac29\frac18$$

The string SSSS can show up on $8$ spots so the probability on a result that contains string SSSS is:$$\frac4{11}\frac3{10}\frac29\frac18\times8=\frac4{165}\approx0.024$$

Comment: That is a great way of thinking about it! But I'm focusing on using the methods of the section I am studying, this tastes like conditional probability (knowing I picked an S, I have 3/10 S left in the bag). But thank you for motivating the next chapter :) and thanks for your time! I will accept as soon as 5 min go by, as the system requires it to be so